# Acquiring client's IP using IPAddress.Any

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking, udp

I am currently working on a simple udp client/server system, and I stumbled upon the following: When I try to get the IP of IPEndPoint (which I fetched using IPAdress.Any)in a program using UdpClient it works and I get the following result (the top one):

[image]

But when I use a normal socket instead of a UdpClient it somehow fails to distinguish the clients/IPs (bottom one). The code for both is listed below. The reason I would like to use sockets is because using the same class for both sending and receiving (not the same instance) is convenient and makes the code far more understandable.

First

```
bool messageReceived = false;
bool done = false;
const int listenPort = 11000;
UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(listenPort);
IPEndPoint receiveEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);
string[] adresses = new string[2];
public void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    int id = 0;
    Byte[] receiveBytes = listener.EndReceive(ar, ref receiveEP);
    for (int i = 0; i < adresses.Length; i++)
    {
        if (adresses[i] == receiveEP.Address.ToString())
        {
            id = i;
            break;
        }
        else if (adresses[i] == null)
        {
            id = i;
            adresses[i] = receiveEP.Address.ToString();
            break;
        }
    }
    byte[] a= Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Is anybody there?");
    listener.Send(a, a.Length, receiveEP);
    Console.WriteLine("Received message from {0} (client {1}):",    adresses[id],id);
    string receiveString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);
    if (receiveString == "stop")
    {
        done = true;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", receiveString);
    messageReceived = true;
}
public void ReceiveMessages()
{
    Console.WriteLine("listening for messages");
    while(!done){
        try
        {
            messageReceived = false;
            if (!messageReceived)
            {
                listener.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback),  null);
            }
            while (!messageReceived)
            {
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Done receiving messages...");
    for (int i = 0; i < adresses.Length; i++)
    {
        if (adresses[i] != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(adresses[i]);
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
    listener.Close();
}'
```

Second

```
bool messageReceived = false;
bool done = false;
const int listenPort = 11000;
Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram,  ProtocolType.Udp);
IPEndPoint receiveEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);
string[] adresses = new string[2];
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
public void ReceiveMessages()
{
    listener.Bind(receiveEP);
    Console.WriteLine("listening for messages");
    while (!done)
    {
        try
        {
            messageReceived = false;
            if (!messageReceived)
            {
                listener.BeginReceive(buffer, 0,1024,SocketFlags.None,new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), null);
            }
            while (!messageReceived)
            {
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Done receiving messages...");
    for (int i = 0; i < adresses.Length; i++)
    {
        if (adresses[i] != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(adresses[i]);
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
    listener.Close();
}
public void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    int id = 0;
    int read = listener.EndReceive(ar);
    for (int i = 0; i < adresses.Length; i++)
    {
        if (adresses[i] == receiveEP.Address.ToString())
        {
            id = i;
            break;
        }
        else if (adresses[i] == null)
        {
            id = i;
            adresses[i] = receiveEP.Address.ToString();
            break;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Received message from {0} (client {1}):", adresses[id], id);
    string receiveString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer,0,read);
    if (receiveString == "stop")
    {
        done = true;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", receiveString);
    messageReceived = true;
}'
```

I've already tried Socket.ReceiveMessageFrom() and using the packetinfo it returned but I ended up with the ip4 of the server even when I send from another machine. Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though this was never supposed to be a Q/A type of question, I've found a way of getting it to work, which means receive() changes the groupEP to the IP of the data packet's sender by just using a Socket instead of an UdpClient (I mimicked the way an UdpClient works). At the moment, it's still synchronous (listener.Receive() is a blocking call) but that will be changed in the near future:

```
    private const int listenPort = 11000;
    public static int Main()
    {
        bool done = false;
        Listener listener = new Listener(listenPort);
        IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        string received_data;
        try
        {
            while (!done)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for broadcast");
                buffer=listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
                received_data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
                Console.WriteLine("Received a broadcast from {0}: {1}", groupEP.ToString(), received_data);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
public class Listener
{
    public Socket client;
    public AddressFamily adressFamily;
    byte[] byte_buffer = new byte[2048];
    public int port;
    public Listener(int p) 
    {
        port=p;
        adressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetwork;
        IPEndPoint localEP;
        localEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
        client = new Socket(this.adressFamily, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        client.Bind(localEP);
    }
    public byte[] Receive(ref IPEndPoint remoteEP)
    {
        IPEndPoint ipEndPoint=new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,port);
        EndPoint endPoint = (EndPoint)ipEndPoint;

        int num = client.ReceiveFrom(byte_buffer, 2048, SocketFlags.None, ref endPoint);
        remoteEP = (IPEndPoint)endPoint;
        if (num < 2048)
        {
            byte[] array = new byte[num];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(byte_buffer, 0, array, 0, num);
            return array;
        }
        return byte_buffer;
    }
```